# Has Biot–Savart law real physics in fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, vortex

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKCK4lJLQHU) from 28:27-36:50 author talk how Bio Sawrt law dont have any physics in aerodynamics, he say it is just math concept and how vorticity cant induce velocity in fluid somewhere in the field..

Has Biot–Savart law real physics in fluids, what is mechanism how vorticity induce velocity in fluids? Is induction cause by viscosity, so if you rotate spoon in bucket of water, after some time  all water will spinning in that direction?

Comment: Is this useful? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313394/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575020/226902